# XSD schema for XML with the same nodes' names

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

There is XML

```
<a>
    <b info="Info1">
        <c info="Info2" />
        <d info="Info3" />
    </b>
    <b info="Info4">
        <e info="Info5" />
        <f info="Info6" />
    </b>
</a>
```

Both blocks with the

```
<b info=...>...</b>
```

element may or may not be present in the XML depending on some unknown external condition. So 4 types of XML are possible for validation:

```
<a/>
<a><b info="Info1"><c info="Info2" /><d info="Info3" /></b></a>
<a><b info="Info4"><e info="Info5" /><f info="Info6" /></b></a>
<a><b info="Info1"><c info="Info2" /><d info="Info3" /></b><b info="Info4"><e info="Info5" /><f info="Info6" /></b></a>
```

XSD schema is generated programmatically. For such a case, the following scheme is generated:

```
<element name="a">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <sequence minOccurs="0">
                <element name="b">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>
                            <info>Info1</info>
                        </documentation>
                    </annotation>
                    <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                            <element name="c">
                                <annotation>
                                    <documentation>
                                        <info>Info2</info>
                                    </documentation>
                                </annotation>
                            </element>
                            <element name="d">
                                <annotation>
                                    <documentation>
                                        <title>Info3</title>
                                    </documentation>
                                </annotation>
                            </element>
                        </sequence>
                    </complexType>
                </element>
            </sequence>
            <sequence minOccurs="0">
                <element name="b">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>
                            <info>Info4</info>
                        </documentation>
                    </annotation>
                    <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                            <element name="e">
                                <annotation>
                                    <documentation>
                                        <info>Info5</info>
                                    </documentation>
                                </annotation>
                            </element>
                            <element name="f">
                                <annotation>
                                    <documentation>
                                        <title>Info6</title>
                                    </documentation>
                                </annotation>
                            </element>
                        </sequence>
                    </complexType>
                </element>
            </sequence>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Such a schema would perfectly describe all possible XML variants if the nested blocks did not contain top-level elements with the same name.

But such a scheme is invalid, since at the same level there are two "b" blocks with the same name. Since these blocks contain different info attributes that must be included in the "annotation" block, they cannot be combined into one.

How can I make such a scheme for all possible cases?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made it clear what the actual rules are, you've only shown us some examples.

But XSD has an absolute rule that if two sibling elements have the same name, then they must have the same declared type.

Comment: What else can I add to my example? I tried to explain this as simply and in detail as possible. I cannot combine them into one declaration as they have different annotation block with description

Comment: Even if I combine <b> elements, how do I make sure that they don't loose their hard linkage with nested elements? And XSD validation throw error, for example, for such XML <a><b info = "Info1" /></a> without nested elements